# asymmetric HMAC

Tags: ssl, hash, digital-signature, hmac

validation of HMAC generated hash requires the key to be known to the validator. So its symmetric. What is the similer asymmetric solution other than SSL ? as I want the signature be smaller like an md5 hash. and the generation and validation procedure to be light. I was going through Rabin's Signature algorithm but couldn't find any Implementation or pseudo code ro follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest asymmetric signatures come from [elliptic curve](http://www.nsa.gov/business/programs/elliptic_curve.shtml) cryptosystems like ECDSA. ECDSA signature schemes require signatures approximately four times the length of a symmetric cipher key of equivalent security. So a scheme comparable in security to 128-bit AES would have 512-bit signatures. That's the state of the art right now -- schemes with smaller signatures but equal or greater security are not known.

If you don't need security quite that high, you could use a 192-bit curve which would result in 384-bit signatures. You can go down to 320-bit signatures (160-bit curves) and still have security comparable to 80-bit symmetric ciphers. If you really don't particularly care about security, 112-bit curves can be used, providing 224-bit signatures that are about as difficult to break as DES.

The following curves are what I would recommend for each security level:

**SecP112R1**: 224-bit signatures, 56-bit security level
**SecP128R1**: 256-bit signatures, 64-bit security level
**SecP160K1**: 320-bit signatures, 80-bit security level
**SecP192K1**: 386-bit signatures, 96-bit security level
**SecP224K1**: 448-bit signatures, 112-bit security level
**SecP256K1**: 512-bit signatures, 128-bit security level

For each curve, the private key is the same size as the curve. Public keys (in compressed form) are one bit larger than the curve size. Signatures are twice the curve size. So with SecP256K1, private keys are 256-bits, public keys are 257-bits, and signatures are 512-bits. These are the minimum sizes for the raw binary values.

**Caution**: I would consider 160-bit curves the minimum for any purpose where security is a factor. Smaller curves might be suitable if keys are generated, used, and then thrown away in a small time frame. For long-term security, 256-bit curves should be used. The system as a whole should be evaluated by competent experts before it is relied upon.

Comment: Can you provide any implementation link ? and its mainly used for what ?

Comment: [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) has an implementation of ECDSA as does [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). ECDSA is used whenever a signature scheme with the absolute smallest possible bit length is needed. (For example, [Bitcoin](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) transactions are secured by SecP256K1 ECDSA signatures.)

Comment: Can you help me a bit more ? I am generating a private key with `openssl ecparam -name secp112r1 -genkey` now I need to generate a public key with what command ? I don't know the openssl commands well.

Comment: You can turn a private key into a compressed public key with `openssl ec -conv_form compressed -pubout` (Note that these forms are a bit larger than the minimums because they contain curve information and type information.)

Comment: Do you know about any bug in openssl 0.9.8 ? cause `openssl dgst -sha1 -sign private.key README` is giving error *`error:0606B06E:digital envelope routines:EVP_SignFinal:wrong public key type:p_sign.c:99:`* and If I am not wrong the same command worked in another machine few hours ago

Comment: Make sure that machine has ECDSA compiled in. Some distributions (notably Fedora) don't include ECDSA in their default OpenSSL build. (You can check with `openssl ec`. If you get an 'invalid command' output, you need to build your own OpenSSL executable.)

Comment: Thanks. However the solution I've designed raises another problem. I thought to say it in comment but its to big to be posted here. can you please check it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957562/openssl-phishing-v-claims-to-be-a-protection