# openssl phishing : V claims to be A

Tags: openssl, public-key-encryption, private-key, encryption-asymmetric, digest

there are several components of my application, needs their communication secure in the sense Origin Verified. these components cannot share a common secret. So I have to opt for asymmetric key encryption. assuming I've two components `A` and `B` A sends some data `F` to `B` and `B` has to verify that it really came from `A`

`A` generates digest `H` of `F` with its private Key
`A` attaches `A_pub`, `H` to its request Parameters, sends `F` and declares origin/sender as `A` 
`B` verifies the digest `H` with the `A_pub` provided against `F`

apparently it looks Okay But if some other component `V` does the same with `V_pub` and claims itself as `A`, `B` still thinks the request came from `A` as this `H` is made with `V_prv` openssl verifies Okay.

I want to give protection against this attack of `V`

I am using `ecparam` `secp112r1` to minimize key length. and keys are repeatedly changed.

-- **EDIT** --

`A`, `B` and `V` are application components identified by unique `URI`. Its currently intended to constraint secure page flow. e.g. you can assume `A`, `B`, `V` be urls What I want is Only `A` can procced to `B` and only `B` can proceed to `C` .... and I don't want to maintain a global/application wide session for that. so If `B` can just verify the origin of this link based on the special parameters `A` have passed to it in a state/session-less manner. and the more generic it can be the more reusable it will be to implement in other scenarios too.

Once I thought to maintain a checksums of `A_pub` in a trusted global storage. however I am afraid wouldn't that be an over engineering ?

another way comes in my mind is to query back the origin url regarding the public key. However I want to avoid that.

Comment: There are two possibilities: 1) `A` and `V` are just arbitrary identifiers (like 'first party' and 'second party') and it doesn't matter which is which so long as `B` keeps them straight. 2) `A` and `V` are not arbitrary and denote something specific. In which case, you won't get a useful answer if you don't tell us what that is.

Answer (score 0):

This technique cannot verify the identity of the sender, only that the keys are a matching pair.

Typically, `B` would already possess some piece of trusted information that it can use to validate `A`'s identity.  The information is generally a copy of `A_pub` that it had previously validated, or that has been signed by a trusted third party, in which case `B` must have access to that third party's public key.

Without this additional information, `B` cannot verify the identity of `A`.

Comment: can you be a bit more elaborate about what are the options ?

Comment: The basis of the Public-Key Infrastructure is that each device maintains a store of trusted certificates.  It uses those certificates to authenticate the identity of other devices.  But it's not possible to verify the identify of a device using _only_ information obtained from that device; there must be a "chain of trust" that ends with information that is known to be genuine.

Comment: How can I generate a certificate on `A_pub` with openssl command line ?

Comment: See http://openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html# for info.  The OpenVPN project used to include a script that would generate certificates; perhaps check there as well.